# How to get sine / cosine value out of tangens

Tags: trigonometry

I know that: $\tan(\alpha) = 1/2$.

How can I get clean values for sine / cosine **without the calculator**?

Is there a relationship?

I know that $\sin(\arctan(1/2))$ is a way ... But I hope you get the point.

Thank you!

Comment: There is not a unique solution unless you make some additional assumption on $\alpha$, such as that $\alpha$ is acute.  In that case, I suggest sketching a right triangle having an angle $\alpha$ with sides chosen such that $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Coming from an algebraic perspective, consider the well-known identity, $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta \equiv 1\, (*)$.

We also know that $\tan \theta \equiv \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\, (**)$. So squaring both sides and using $(*)$ on the denominator gives

$$\tan^2 \theta = \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{1-\sin^2 \theta}$$

This rearranges to

$$\sin^2 \theta = \frac{\tan^2 \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta}$$

This is the best we can do, because $(**)$ above holds if we replace $(\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$ by $(-\sin \theta, -\cos \theta)$, so it's impossible to obtain the sign of $\sin \theta$ from only knowing the value of $\tan \theta$.

We can then obtain an expression for $\cos^2 \theta$ by using $(*)$ again, namely

$$\cos^2 \theta = \frac{1}{1+\tan^2 \theta}$$

Comment: Great algebraic answer! The rearrangment part where we get 1+tan^2 Θ could be unclear for some. Maybe to mention relations/identities: sec Θ=1/sqrt(1-sin^2 Θ) and 1+tan^2 Θ=sec^2 to make the answer more complete. I suggest to readers to lean on graphical presentation of the relation between the triangles. There we can logically make a conclusion what is what and why this is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by Jonas:

1) Draw a right triangle and label one of the (non $90^\circ$) angles $\alpha$.

[image]

2) You know that the tangent of $\alpha$ is ${1\over2}$.  Since $\tan={\text{opposite}\over \text{adjacent}}$, you can label the  side of the triangle adjacent to $\alpha$  "1" and the opposite side "2".

[image]

3) By the Pythagorean theorem, you can find the length of the hypotenuse of the triangle.

[image]

4) Now you can read $\sin(\alpha)$ from the completed triangle. And remember sin from the angle is opposite/hypotenuse - 1/radical 5

This will give you one solution. There is another solution, given when $\alpha$ is a third quadrant angle.

Comment: Nice and simple!

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the cosine as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
cos^2 x + \sin^2 x &= 1 \\
\cos^2 x + \cos^2x \tan^2 x &= 1 \\
\cos^2 x(1 + \tan^2 x) &= 1 \\
\cos x &= \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 x}}
\end{align*}
$$

Then $\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x}$

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the second line, specifically how `tan^2 x` got in to the equation?

Comment: $\tan(x) = \sin x \cos x$ by defintion, so $\sin^2 x = \cos^2 x (\sin^2 x \cos^2 x) = \cos^2 x \tan^2 x$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algebraic solution.

Recall that $\tan \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$. Now your equation states that
$$\sin \alpha = \frac{1}{2}\cos \alpha.$$

Squaring both sides gives
$$\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4} \cos^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{4}(1 - \sin^2 \alpha).$$
Or
$$\sin^2 \alpha = \frac{1}{5}.$$
Similarly one sees that
$$\cos^2 \alpha = \frac{4}{5}.$$

Thus the possibilities are $$\sin \alpha = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \quad \cos \alpha = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

We still have to show that these possibilities are possible. We know that there is $\alpha$ such that $\tan \alpha = \frac{1}{2}$. I.e. the original equation has a solution. Now if $\alpha$ is a solution, so is $\alpha + \pi$. From this we can deduce that both $\sin \alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $\sin \alpha = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ are attainable and so are $\cos \alpha = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$. Moreover the signs must be the same for both. Thus the solutions are
$$(\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha) \in \{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}), (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})\}.$$